# Generating sum when reading file line-by-line

Tags: python, sum

I am having some trouble generating the sum of some numbers when reading a file line-by-line. I want to calculate the sum from a separate file without saving the numbers as a list. Is there an easy command for this? My code looks like this:

```
def imput(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: #open the file
        for line in f:
            input('sample.txt')`
```

The file 'sample.txt' consists of the numbers `1,2,4,6,8` and when I use the print function I get:

```
print(line)

1

2

4

6

8
```

Comment: Are the numbers all on one line, or all separate lines?

Comment: All separate lines.

Comment: Hmm you confused me with the 2 different files i dont know whats going on

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to total number like:

#### Code:

```
total = sum(int(line) for line in open('file1', 'rU'))
print(total)
```

And if you like the terseness of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) that can be even shorter as:

```
total = sum(map(int, open('file1', 'rU')))
```

#### Results:

```
21
```

Comment: perfect use of `sum(map(int,open('file1', 'rU')))`. only default is that you don't know when the file will be closed.